# Cloning BitLocker encrypted disk to VMWare Fusion image?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, parallels, bitlocker

I have a ThinkPad running Windows 7 Enterprise with a BitLocker encrypted drive. I would like to clone or somehow convert this physical machine into a virtual machine that I can with either VMWare Fusion 5 or Parallels Desktop 8 on OS X.

Is this even possible given the BitLocker encryption?

Comment: Why not disable BitLocker and be done with it?

Answer (score 3):

[VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/overview.html) should be able to convert it. You may need to disable BitLocker, decrypting the entire drive, first, since BitLocker is not supported within virtual machines.